# How to prevent Rails ujs remote form submit from jumping to top of page?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rails-ujs

I have multiple ujs forms on a page, and when clicking submit on the forms lower down on the page, the page jumps back up to the top.  All ujs functionality is working correctly, but I'd like the page to stay put after submit.  The DOM elements being updated are near the submit button, and not near the top of the page.  Is there a way to preventDefault() in the actions js.erb file without wrapping its contents in a function?  If not, how can I wrap the js.erb contents in a functions...since I don't need any sort of a lister?

Comment: This is not the default behavior, can you paste code here?

Comment: Thanks @RajdeepSingh!  I started to edit my question to post relevant code.  Your comment reminded me that this is not the default behavior and should not be something I need to correct.  When I posted the form here, I realized I had a custom button_tag being used for submit...and not a simple f.submit.  Switching to f.submit fixed my issue.